# xcode 9.4.1Created static library framework error reporting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

SThe code was developed using xcode 9.3, and I upgraded to xcode 9.4, framework some static libraries reported red.

I also removed xcode 9.4 and installed xcode 9.3, but some of the framework's static libraries reported red。

The official framework has also gone red

Build Setting->Search Paths -> Frameworks Search Paths, Header Seacrh Paths,Library Search Paths The specified path is added.The path selects recursive

General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries  -The number is deleted, and the number + is added again or red.

I think it's xcode 9.4. How do you recover it?

[Project screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZiuz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have multiple `.xcodeproj` file in your project. So my suggestion, Please build your project for each target then your framework automatically genrated respected location.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand, so to speak, I understand

Comment: What is this procedure??

Comment: Xcode has fixed this error.. Static library paths have been referenced normally